# Iterate over items in Tuple

Tags: c#, loops, tuples, console-application

I have this method with three loops:

```
    public void Print(Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>, List<string>> dataToPrint)
    {
        foreach (var item in dataToPrint.Item1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in dataToPrint.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in dataToPrint.Item3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to use only one loop to print all the items with contents of the Lists on the screen?

Comment: Is it a problem to change the type?

Comment: Why are you even using a `Tuple` here? If all lists have the same length, then, in any case, use a `List<Tuple<...>>` and if not, then simply implement a builder method that prints out a list, and call it three times.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking @ InBetween, but they might not have the same length

Comment: The order in which it prints out that you've shown is that a requirement? Ie all items in the first list and then all items in the second etc. Or can you have item 1 of each list then item 2 of each list etc?

Comment: Yes, the order is a requirement. The lists have the same length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, of course, concat all lists into one sequence of `object` or `string` items, but this concatenation will not make your code more readable. But you can create simple extension method which dumps content of any sequence to the console:

```
public static void Dump<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
       Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

And your code will look like (no loops at all):

```
public void Print(Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>, List<string>> dataToPrint)
{
    dataToPrint.Item1.Dump();
    dataToPrint.Item2.Dump();
    dataToPrint.Item3.Dump();
}
```

I would also use named parameters, custom type or value tuple to pass these three values to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to be sure that all lists have the same length.
You could basically do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataToPrint.Item1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataToPrint.Item1[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(dataToPrint.Item2[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(dataToPrint.Item3[i]);
}
```

Comment: This would print in a different order to the original code. Not sure if that is an issue

Comment: I though this was what OP wanted. But indeed, this will not have the same output as the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Calling ForEach(Console.WriteLine) on a list of datetimes won't actually work as Console.WriteLine does not have a specific override that takes a date time it just uses the override that takes an object. Since List.ForEach expects an Action and the Console.WriteLine method required to write a datetime is infact an Action this code wont compile, so this answer isn't correct. However I think its pretty interesting to see why it wont work, so I'll leave it here

I'm not sure really why you have a problem with the code there. If that is the signature of the method and you can't change it then that to me seems valid. If you for some reason really want to limit your lines code you can do this

```
dataToPrint.Item1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
dataToPrint.Item2.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
dataToPrint.Item3.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Some others have suggested a for loop of all the lists are the same length but this will print out in a different order to what you have described. And cast all the items in all the lists into objects so you can contat the lists could be costly thanks to boxing your value types like double.
Edit: I've been informed that the boxing is probably negligible compared to the performance of writing to then console. However I still think casting them all to object isnt the best option, but that's just me

Comment: The first line gives following error: CS0123 No overload for 'Console.WriteLine(object)' matches delegate 'Action<DateTime>

Comment: I wrote this on my phone. Once at my laptop let me check my syntax and I'll get back to you

Comment: Well they say you learn something new everyday. Console.WriteLine() does not have a specific overload to that takes a DateTime, it resolves to user the overload that just takes an object. Thanks to what I'm guessing is some issues with co/contra -variance, List<T>.ForEach takes an Action<T> and the compiler does not like that your list of DateTime is have ForEach called on it and is in fact being passed an Action<object> not Action<DateTime> ... so inshort my answer wont work, I'm going to leave it there and edit it though, because I think its quite interesting

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach (var element in dataToPrint.Item1.Cast<object>().Concat(dataToPrint.Item2.Cast<object>()).Concat(dataToPrint.Item3.Cast<object>()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Comment: Depending on how big those lists are, could this not have a performance hit from boxing (and unboxing?) the value types ?

Comment: i think Console.WriteLine ist the slowest part - boxing and unboxing should not matter that much.

Comment: I didn't know it was particularly costly. I'll keep that mind in the future

Comment: Why would you ever want to box a value type when all you need is its string representation? Concat everything into an `IEnumerable<string>`, `ToString` will be called anyways, do it upfront.